# How can I get current language from TranslateService to use in an HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have noticed that Angular doesn't add the `Accept-Language` header to requests and I would like to be able to check the language on the backend.

I was trying to do the following:

*version 1:*

```js
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private translateService: TranslateService
    ) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.debug("Request intercepted by AuthInterceptor.");
        return next.handle(
            req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.append(
                    "Accept-Language", this.translateService.currentLang
                )
            })
        );      
    }
}
```

*version 2:*

```js
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private injector: Injector
    ) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.debug("Request intercepted by AuthInterceptor.");
        return next.handle(
            req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.append(
                    "Accept-Language", this.injector.get(TranslateService).currentLang
                )
            })
        );        
    }
}
```

But none of this work. I assume that the TranslateService can't be used here, like in a component. If so, then how can I get the selected language and use it in the interceptor?

---

**Update:**
With version 1, I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:200)
    at http.js:171
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.init (http.js:171)
    at HttpHeaders.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:236)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1436)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at subscribeTo.js:21
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
```

Comment: What did not working in *version 1*.  Did it not read the value or did it not inject the `TranslationService`, or something else?

Comment: I have updated my question with the error info @Igor

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you get a reference outside the `next.handle`, log it to the console, and then consume it in the header assignment? `const lang = this.translateService.currentLang; console.log('lang is ', lang); return.... "Accept-Language", lang ...`

Comment: Yeap, still the same thing.

Comment: Does the `console.log` line print out the value of the current language? If so the failure has nothing to do with the TranslateService but has to do with how the headers are being manipulated in the interceptor.

Comment: Maybe if you do `request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { 'your-custom-header': value },
      });` before `return next.handle(request)` would help?

Comment: I add other headers in this way (I have removed them, because I don't think that it matters) and everything works correctly, until I add this header from the ngx-translate module. My intuition says that it has something to do with the fact that it is not really possible to use it in the injector? What confuses me is the error message, which gives me no clue as to where the problem is...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... Any luck here?

Answer (score 0):

try use the version 1, use `${this.translateService.currentLang}` insted of `this.translateService.currentLang`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it that way for HttpInterceptor. However, in the first installation, you can write the language in the storage and call it again. Something like the following might work for you.

[image]